# Need help aligning a text

Tags: html, css

```
      Age: 23
   Location: Bronx,NY
Nationality: Puerto Rican
  Ocupation: Tailor
```

You can see a live example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MUFcb/1/)

Comment: check my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MUFcb/11/ below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated it for you here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/MUFcb/11/

Added `<span>` with CSS to give the alignment you were looking for in your example.

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="personal">
   <ul>
       <li><span class="label">Age:</span> 23</li>
       <li><span class="label">Location:</span> Bronx,NY</li>
       <li><span class="label">Nationality:</span> Puerto Rican</li>
       <li><span class="label">Ocupation:</span> Tailor</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#personal ul li span.label{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 75px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I like this one because it keeps in the context of divs using an span was very good here

Comment: if there is not data the label then will float left, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: can you show an example of this in JSFiddle w/ the updated code? I'll fix it for ya.

Comment: thank pixelbobby this made it #personal li  {
list-style:none;
clear:both;
}

Comment: I need it to clear it the li tag. talk to you later need to go for the moment thanks.

Comment: PixelBobby can you =help me in the re-order of the profile here http://jsfiddle.net/ZrNaa/80/ I am not sure if the map, description, picture and comment are well positioned. thanks I will appriciate your help pixelbobby.

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd use a `dl` (Definition list) here as you are defining a term - `dt`, then giving 'description' - `dd`, on each term.. the good thing is you get the two parts you need to align however you'd like ;)

[Definition Lists:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#edef-DL)

> Definition lists vary only slightly
>   from other types of lists in that list
>   items consist of two parts: a term and
>   a description. The term is given by
>   the DT element and is restricted to
>   inline content. The description is
>   given with a DD element that contains
>   block-level content.

then you can float the `dt` 's

**CSS:**

```
dl {border: 1px solid #000;}
dt {float: left; width: 180px; text-align: right; margin-right: 20px;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="personal">
    <dl>
       <dt>Age:</dt> <dd>23</dd>
       <dt>Location:</dt> <dd>Bronx,NY</dd>
       <dt>Nationality:</dt><dd>Puerto Rican</dd>
       <dt>Ocupation:</dt><dd>Tailor</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

### Example: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/LY3xv/)

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to use a table for that sort of data, not an unordered list...

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Age:</td>
      <td>23</td>
   </tr>
   ...
   ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a table here.

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Age:</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Location:</td>
      <td>Bronx,NY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Nationality:</td>
      <td>Puerto Rican</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ocupation:</td>
      <td>Tailor</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use a table you can also use divs that have a style of **float:left**

```
<div style="float:left;">
       Age: <br />
       Location: <br />
       Nationality: <br />
       Ocupation: <br />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
       23<br/>
       Bronx,NY<br/>
       Puerto Rican<br/>
       Tailor<br/>
    </div>
```

If you want the age to be right-aligned, you can add **text-align:right** to that div.

Answer (score 0):

what about this one ? if you want the spaces less then just change the padding value
    http://jsfiddle.net/MUFcb/8/